# Volume keeps resetting for different audios - ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have an app that plays 3 different audios. I have a volume control slider. 
For a single audio, it works fine.

However, if I change the audio, then the volume automatically becomes maximum. Here is the flow:

1. Playing audio 1.
2. I reduce the volume using the slider and bring it near zero (not zero, but very low volume).
3. Now I select audio 2.
4. The volume should be low. But it becomes maximum again.

This is the code:

```
@IBAction func volumeSlidercontroller(_ sender: UISlider) {

    player.volume = volumeSlider.value;
```

I am including screenshots for slider value.

[image: slider description]

This is the code for player:

```
@IBAction func music1(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fire1", ofType: "mp3")
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()


        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)

        UserDefaults.standard.set("fire1", forKey: "music")
        toggleButton(button: music01, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music select"), offImage:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music select"))
        toggleButton(button: music02, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"))

        toggleButton(button: music03, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"))
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(true, forKey: "InstructionsButtonIsHidden")

//            let sounddefaults = UserDefaults.standard
//            player.pause()
        onoffLabel.setTitle("on", for: .normal)

//            sounddefaults.set(true, forKey: "soundMute")





}

@IBAction func music2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fire2", ofType: "mp3")
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
    player.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()


    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)



    UserDefaults.standard.set("fire2", forKey: "music")
    toggleButton(button: music02, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music select"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music select"))
    toggleButton(button: music03, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"))
    toggleButton(button: music01, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"))

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "InstructionsButtonIsHidden")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "volumeValue")

//        let sounddefaults = UserDefaults.standard
//        
//        sounddefaults.set(true, forKey: "soundMute")
    onoffLabel.setTitle("on", for: .normal)

}

@IBAction func music3(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fire3", ofType: "mp3")
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
    player.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()


    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)



    UserDefaults.standard.set("fire3", forKey: "music")
    toggleButton(button: music03, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music select"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music select"))
    toggleButton(button: music02, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"))
    toggleButton(button: music01, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "music unselect"))

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "InstructionsButtonIsHidden")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "volumeValue")

//        let sounddefaults = UserDefaults.standard
//        
//        sounddefaults.set(true, forKey: "soundMute")
    onoffLabel.setTitle("on", for: .normal)


}



func SetUpSound() {

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fire1", ofType: "mp3") {
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
        player.prepareToPlay() 
        player.play()
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)
}
```

Is there a way to play the audio with previously fixed volume? i.e, If I kept low volume for audio 1, it should be low for audio 2 also. It should not become maximum. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you play the next audio, are you setting the player volume again?

Comment: @totiG Well, no. So setting that can work?

Comment: It can work. I think it depends on how you are playing the next audio file. Are you recreating your player? Can you show your play method.

Comment: @totiG Sure. Just included it in the question :)

Comment: @totiG I'm looking to do small app like face track and i've shared link below youtube.com/watch?v=jP3HDIhc10Y . Is there any tutorial, can you please share ideas with me. –

Comment: This should be a new question. Comments should be about the question that has been asked.

Comment: @totiG When playing a sound with AVAudioPlayer the volume is very low

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating the AVAudioPlayer every time you play the next audio file. This means the previous volume setting you set, is now discarded. Add this line to where you create the audio player:

```
player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
player.volume = volumeSlider.value
```

The problem with using your own volume control slider in this way is you are not adjusting the system volume - but this may actually be what you want. So if the devices volume is set to 50%, and the user then sets your slider to 100% - this will still only be at 50% volume. You may want to have a look at MPVolumeView which gives you access to the system volume slider, this would always affect the AVAudioPlayer and you will not need to set the player volume directly. It also gives you access to the Airplay icon so that a user could easily play your audio on a bluetooth or Airplay device such as the Apple TV.

Another thing is you are repeating the same code throughout. You could tidy this up by having a play function that you just pass the audio file name to, like this:

```
func playAudio(name: String) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp3")
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
    player.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
}
```

You could then just call this:

```
@IBAction func music1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    playAudio(name: "fire1")
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: I'm looking to do small app like face track and i've shared link below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP3HDIhc10Y . Is there any tutorial, can you please share ideas  with me.